# Minimo valor de una lista

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy armando una lista

```
lista.append(['{}{}'.format('Metros: ', metros),nombre,direccion])
```

y la salida es:

```
[['Metros: 405', 'edificio A', 'San Lorenzo'], ['Metros: 1843', 'edificio B', 'Eusebio Blanco'], ['Metros: 3067', 'edificio C', 'Av. San Martín Sur , Godoy Cruz'], ['Metros: 2863', 'edificio D', 'Tomás Godoy Cruz']]
```

Como puedo obtener de la lista el valor minimo de Metros.

En este ejemplo deberia de devolver

> ['Metros: 405', 'edificio A', 'San Lorenzo']

Comment: Podrías guiarte con esta respuesta: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5320895/3239070. Pero para eso, tendrías que generar tu lista como [{'Metro':Valor,'Edificio':NombreEdiicion...}...], que me parece una forma más comprensible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma muy compacta de resolverlo podría ser:

```
lista = [['Metros: 405', 'edificio A', 'San Lorenzo'], 
         ['Metros: 1843', 'edificio B', 'Eusebio Blanco'], 
         ['Metros: 3067', 'edificio C', 'Av. San Martín Sur , Godoy Cruz'], 
         ['Metros: 2863', 'edificio D', 'Tomás Godoy Cruz']]

print(min([(e,float(e[0].split()[1])) for e in lista],key = lambda x: x[1])[0])

['Metros: 405', 'edificio A', 'San Lorenzo']
```

**Detalle**:

- Por comprensión de listas: `[(e,float(e[0].split()[1])) for e in lista]` armamos una nueva lista de tuplas que contendrá el elemento original junto con los metros llevados a un`float`. Con [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) separamos el primer elemento de cada lista (los metros) por el espacio ya que solo nos interesa el número.
- Usamos [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html?highlight=min#min) sobre la lista anterior, indicando sobre que índice de las tuplas se aplicará: `key = lambda x: x[1]`

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 2):

Deberías considerar transformar la listas de listas en un lista de diccionarios si es posible como te comenta @MLStud, estas operaciones serían mucho más simples y eficientes sobretodo usando `operator.itemgetter` y `min`/`max`, solo a modo de idea:

```
lista = [{'Metros': 405,   "Nombre": 'edificio A', "Direccion": 'San Lorenzo'},
         {'Metros': 1843,  "Nombre": 'edificio B', "Direccion": 'Eusebio Blanco'},
         {'Metros': 3067,  "Nombre": 'edificio C', "Direccion": 'Av. San Martín Sur , Godoy Cruz'},
         {'Metros': 2863,  "Nombre": 'edificio D', "Direccion": 'Tomás Godoy Cruz'}]


from operator import itemgetter

minimo = min(lista, key=itemgetter("Metros"))
```

---

```
>>> minimo
{'Metros': 405, "Nombre": 'edificio A', "Direccion": 'San Lorenzo'}
```

Puedes construir el diccionario  y añadirlo a la lista con:

```
lista.append({'Metros': metros, 'Nombre': nombre, 'Direccion': direccion})
```

Si no puedes hacer esto, puedes usar igualmente el built-in `min` y su argumento `key` pero pasándole una función que se encargue de tomar cada sublista, tomar el primer item, obtener el número aplicando `str.rsplit` y pasarlo  a `float` o `int` (para no llevar a cabo un ordenamiento lexicográfico). Esto es significativamente más ineficiente que usar un diccionario ya que requiere una llamada a función en Python puro, llamada a `str.rsplit` y casting a escalar y dos operaciones de indexado sobre listas (mientras que el ejemplo anterior se realiza mayoritariamente por medio de  código C compilado directamente):

```
minimo = min(lista, key=lambda item: float(item[0].rsplit(" ", maxsplit=1)[-1]))
```

---

```
>>> minimo 
['Metros: 405', 'edificio A', 'San Lorenzo']
```

> **Nota:** `rsplit(" ", maxsplit=1)` busca el primer espacio en la cadena de derecha a izquierda y rompe ahí la cadena sin seguir buscando más.

Comment: tengo un error **E1101:Instance of 'dict' has no 'append' member** al crear el diccionario **lista.append[{'Metros': metros, 'Edificio': nombre, 'Direccion': direccion}]**

Comment: Seba disculpa, tenia un error tipográfico en la línea, debe ser     `lista.append({'Metros': metros, 'Nombre': nombre, 'Direccion': direccion})`. Dónde `lista` debe ser una lista, valga la redundancia... Si partes de una lista vacía la puedes crear de forma más eficiente mediante una lista por compresión, pero sería necesario conocer como obtienes y de donde las tres variables.

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona perfecto

Answer (score 1):

```
min=-1
for x in lista:
   #Aqui miro si nunca ha habido un minimo y pongo el primero de la lista.
   if(min == -1):
      min=x.Metros
      menor=x
   #Comprobamos si es menor
   elif(x.Metros < min):
      min=x.Metros
      menor=x
#Imprimimos el menor
print menor
```

Con eso deberia de funcionar

Answer (score 1):

Siguiendo con la respuesta de Martin, se me ocurre algo para optimizar el código.
En vez de crear una variable con un número muy bajo y sobreescribirla si no lo ha sido aún, podrías crear esa variable con un número muy alto, que nunca vayas a alcanzar, y de ahí ir comparándola con los diversos números.

```
    min=  #el número que quieras pero que sea más grande que cualquiera de los que puedas tener (una exageración vamos)
for x in lista:
   if(min < x.Metros):
      min=x.Metros 
#Se imprime el menor
print min
```

Creo que con eso bastaría c: